# How to use ES6 object extension mark `...`?

Tags: javascript, spread-syntax

As the subject, is it OK to use `...` in that way to copy properties in an object to another?

Chrome always throws syntax error when I was trying to use it in an object like:

```js
var a = function(){
  return {c: 2};
}

var b = {...a()};
```

Comment: Yes, `var b = { ...a() }` is valid syntax.

Comment: fyi, `...` (3 dots) is what they called spread syntax.

Comment: Works good in my Chrome: http://prntscr.com/j2tihf

Comment: What version of chrome are you using? I checked with 63 . Working without an error

Comment: [Object spread](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax#Spread_in_object_literals) is supported in Chrome 60, and is an expiremental feature.

Comment: Spread syntax in object literals is supported in Chrome since version 60: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax#Browser_compatibility

Comment: this is a new syntax it will only work new versions of crhome

Comment: Yeah, mine was 59, I just updated it, now this piece of code is working fine with this spread syntax, THX:)

Answer (score 0):

In es2018 the spread syntax if applied to an object behaves like `object.assign`.

```
var obj1 = { a: 1 }
var obj2 = function() { return {b:2} };
var obj3 = { ...obj1, ..obj2 }
```

The result would be a new object with combine properties of obj1 and obj2. So obj3 would now be `{ a:1, b2 }`.

Comment: It’s part of ES2018, not ES6.

Comment: @Xufox As done in the question, yes. `For object literals (new in ECMAScript 2018).` [MDN Spread Syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax).

Comment: You're missing a dot and an invocation at `obj2`

Comment: … and a colon at `b2`.

Comment: My chrome version was 59, and I updated it, with version 65 now the problem is gone, I am not missing anything, now the code is running in chrome console perfectly. THX:), this answer is missing a dot before obj2:( it seems, but this method does look like Object.assign